# Arduino Mega - get mac adress

Tags: ethernet

I am new on Arduino, and I am trying to use the Ethernet shield...

but it need:

- IP adress
- MAC adress

IP adress is easy to get... but not MAC..

how can I get my arduino MAC adress?

Answer (score 3):

A MAC address must be unique throughout the environment in which it operates, but apart from that is largely arbitrary.  Typically the problem is solved by selling 3-octet prefixes (called OUI's) to manufacturers, who then uniquely assign the remaining 3 octets to individual device units they manufacturer.

However, if you are unable to discovery a globally unique address assigned to your device by its manufacturer, and know that its traffic will be confined to a local network, you can use a privately assigned (ie, "made up") address with the **Locally Administered** bit set.   An address of the form

```
02-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx-xx
```

or any other with the 2's bit of the first octet set will satisfy this criteria as long as you guarantee that it is unique in your system.

Be especially careful not to set the 1's bit of the first octet - if you do so, traffic will be marked as broadcast and so given wider distribution/attention than needed, wasting network capacity and processor time of connected devices.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino doesn't have a MAC address, your Ethernet adapter shield however will. The MAC address is likely printed on the interface and is constructed from 12 hexadecimal numbers, usually grouped 2 hex digits at a time.

If it isn't printed on the box or the shield, then the only way to find out is to connect it to your network, configure a valid IP address on the shield and try to connect to it (eg. ping to the address) from your PC) Then you can list MAC addresses from your PC  with `arp -a`.

Or when using dynamic addresses and DHCP, you can find the mac address in you DHCP server (probably your home router).

Either way, you need a sketch on your Arduino to configure an IP address.

Comment: i cant vote for you... i dont have reputation =(

Comment: This answer seems somewhat at odds with the documentation cited in the other - if the shield has to be told its MAC address by the sketch, then you can't meaningfully query it until you have done that.

Comment: No MAC address is hard wired, IP address is configured in software @ChrisStratton Arduino doesn't have a MAC address, the Ethernet NIC does. Arduino can probably overrule the hard wired address, but that is advanced use of the shield.

Comment: @ChrisStratton according the the other answer some shields come without a hard wired MAC address. When inventing your own address it is essential to make it unique on your network.

Comment: Yes, it's quite clear that some come without an address stored in the hardware, what is unclear is that any come with.  Certainly though there are other embedded devices and adapters that have one stored in an eeprom or similar, bridge devices with a network stack in flash and an address stored alongside it, etc.

Comment: @ChrisStratton With a regular NIC (network interface card) as the one in your computer, tv, phone, ... the MAC address is always hard wired. This obviously is not a complete NIC, just some sort of bare bone.

Comment: Actually, no, it's usually not hard wired in the MAC, but rather stored somewhere outside the MAC chip (an eeprom on a classic ethernet card), queried from there by the software and then injected into a register in the chip by software... serializaton of ICs that aren't otherwise programmable is expensive.

Comment: I guess the more the Ethernet interface can offload workload from the microcontroller, the more tasks are done on the Ethernet interface. If you have a Ethernet interface without hard wired MAC, then your microcontroller will be much busier with communications than an interface with hard wired MAC (and related 'accelerating' hardware).

Comment: Although I can't comment on all the specifics of this, I can say that the [official ethernet library documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin) implies that you can choose your own mac with: *older Arduino Ethernet Shields include a sticker with the device's MAC address. For older shields, choose your own.*

Comment: @jippie - normally except in a "promiscuous mode" the MAC chip handles filtering of incoming packets by MAC address (so the processor doesn't have to), but by using an address set in a volatile register - which has to be externally loaded from some other source of information at power on / reset.  If you have something like an ethernet<>serial bridge where the whole network stack is running on a dedicated embedded processor, then that probably does have the MAC address persistently stored, though again, not typically actually within its ethernet functional block but rather elsewhere inside.

Answer (score 1):

> Current Ethernet shields come with a sticker indicating the MAC address you should use with them.

([source](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoEthernetShield))

Comment: my Ethernet shield doesnt :( it is not the official

Comment: Ultimately, all but a few bits of the MAC address are irrelevant - they only need to be globally unique.  There is a range of MAC addresses reserved for "locally administered values" (ie, a range in which you are allowed to make up your own).  Pragmatically speaking, you can also take the address off an obsolete device you physically possess (old ISA bus NIC?) and know is not in use.